# Persistent parameters between requests in Dart

Tags: http, dart, request

I am trying to get data from an API, but beforehand I need to login with another request.

Here's an easy exemple :

```
s.get('https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789')
final response = s.get('https://httpbin.org/cookies')
```

I tried in python with `requests.Session()` and that works just fine, but I don't seems to find anything that could do that in dart.

So what I need is something that can store parameters between requests.

**EDIT 1:**

Just tried with `dio_cookie_manager` :

```dart
Dio dio =  Dio();
CookieJar cookieJar = CookieJar();

dio.interceptors.add(CookieManager(cookieJar));
cookieJar.loadForRequest(Uri.parse("https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789"));
var response = await dio.get("https://httpbin.org/cookies");
print(response.body); // -> {cookies: {}}
```

So that also doesn't work.

**EDIT 2 :**

Seems to work with `"https://baidu.com/"` but don't know where it went wrong with the other one..

Comment: You should try to use [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) with its [cookie manager](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/tree/master/plugins/cookie_manager)

Comment: I tried with `dio_cookie_manager` , but that doesn't seems to work with `httpbin.org`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`requests`](https://pub.dev/packages/requests) package was a solution for me, be sure to include [`shared_preferences`](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) as a dependency in your pubspec.yaml file.